# Sending an image file from android to flask server

Tags: android, python, flask, jpeg, okhttp

I'm trying to send an image from an android app to a flask server. I'm using OkHttp, and the image is a file saved on the phone. Here is the post request code:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(RequestBody.create(IMGJPEG, imageFile))
        .build();
```

and here's the receiving code

```
img = request.get_data()
f = open('image.jpeg','w')
f.write(img)
```

The file created has a 10kB difference with the file on the phone (2,432,933 bytes on the phone and 2,442,645 bytes on the server). What is the extra data, and how do I strip it?

Comment: You seem to be treating the entire request body as a file. But that will have lots of other things in it.

Comment: How would I go about finding out what is just the file and what is the extra stuff?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: I tried some of the things on there and I think the issue is about how I'm sending the image. Does the code seem correct?